# What SPSS analysis should I use? Anova / Ancova

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, ancova

I am conducting an experiment where participants are randomly assigned to one of 2 training groups.

Participants are tested on 6 intelligence questionnaires,whereby they are scored on a points system.  3/6 will be related broadly to each on of the training techniques.  They are then assigned to 1 of the 2 training groups, and retested a week later.

However, as I have been out of college for some time I am struggling to figure out whether I should be using and anova or ancova or what ?

The aim of the experiment is to find out whether test scores can be improved through training.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

*EDIT* I would also be interested to see if age or gender affect performance improvements

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing the same people more than once, your data is not going to be independent.  This violates the assumptions of both ANOVA and ANCOVA.  I recommend a multilevel model.  Since you are evidently a novice at statistics, I also recommend hiring someone to do this for you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I can;t hire somebody, this is just for an assignment.  I am a novice but just need to know analysis type then I will have no problem executing it on SPSS